# Lubuntu 16 slowand choppy in decent laptop

Tags: lubuntu, performance

I have a an old laptop which specs are DualCore CPU, 4 GB RAM and 500 GB of hard drive.

So although is old, it should be waaaay more than needed to run Lubuntu. But it is not, its extremely laggy, and choppy.

I dont think the culprit is on RAM usage since it even lags in the terminal emulator, where I would press key alls and have to literally wait for a few seconds before they are shown.

If I check the cpu usage with top, i can see that although no process is consuming too much, the cpu itself seems to be at 60% all the time.

Its IMPOSSIBLE to watch a youtube video. Not only is super choppy but Firefox even crashes after a few seconds of playback.

I guess that it might be related to the video drivers. But I am unsure how to proceed to troubleshoot that.

What do you folks recommend?

Note: Windows 7 runs "well". Obvioualy it struggles here and ther but overall it runs smooth. I can watch youtube at 60 fps with no issues there.

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: FYI: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://lubuntu.me/xenial-5-released/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Lubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.  *Lubuntu is a desktop thus uses the yy.mm format*

Comment: FYI:  Yes you are right it should be fine. I used pentium 4 & pentium M single core boxes with 1GB of RAM for testing Lubuntu releases up to and into Lubuntu 19.04 cycle (all *amd64* boxes have 2GB of ram or more). Performance on watching youtube *vids* did vary on video card, but never crashed (I use `sudo lshw -C video` to get basic info) but there is no Lubuntu 16 (*yy* is used only for *snap* based releases, desktops & servers use *yy.mm*), and all 2016 *flavor* releases are now EOL.